# like has/like it has/as has - comparison

Tags: phrase-usage

> **A**: I hope you like the letter I wrote you. Or **like has** happened before, you might not.
>
> **B**: I hope you like the letter I wrote you. Or **like it has** happened before, you might not.
>
> **C**: I hope you like the letter I wrote you. Or **as has** happened before, you might not.

Are all these sentences grammatically correct and mean the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **like/as** as a conjunction meaning **in the way that**, to introduce the [subordinate clause](https://englishsentences.com/subordinate-clause/) "...has happened before".

This is what the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/like) has to say about using **like** as a conjunction.

> In informal contexts, we can use like as a conjunction instead of as. Traditional grammar books consider this use of like incorrect:
>
> **Like** any good cook book will tell you, don’t let the milk boil. - *informal, some would say incorrect* 
>  
>   **As** any good cook book will tell you, don’t let the milk boil. - *correct*

I would therefore advise against using the two 'like' sentences unless you know the people that you are speaking to and they routinely use 'like' in this way.

---

Note that, when you introduce a subordinate clause in the middle of a sentence (i.e. not the start or the end), it is normal to enclose the clause in commas. In case you didn't notice, that's exactly what I did in the previous sentence. In your sentence, it would be better to put the clause between a pair of commas. This means adding one more comma after 'Or' in your sentence:

> I hope you like the letter i wrote you. Or, as has happened before, you might not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about "grammatically correct," but I think **B** sounds clumsy and **A** sounds awkward.

My choice of the three would be to use **C**.

I'd probably add a comma after the word *or*, too:

> I hope you like the letter I wrote you. Or, as has happened before, you might not.